# dependency on a single test suit causes other test suits to fail - Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I am mocking the following library on one of my test suits:

it's react-native-awesome-card.io:

```
jest.mock('react-native-awesome-card-io', () => {
  return {
    CardIOUtilities: {
      preload: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('the response')),
    },
  }
})

    describe('PaymentDetails', () => {
      test('snapshot = PaymentDetails not empty', () => {
        const options = {
          navigation: {
            state: {
              params: {
                paymentMethod: {
                  accountName: 'Test Account',
                  expMonth: 11,
                  expYear: 2021,
                  number: '4111111111111111',
                  type: 'Visa',
                  preferred: true,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          getUserInfo: { locale: 'en-US' },
        }
        snapshot(shallow(<PaymentDetails {...options} />))
      })
```

This seems to work fine for this test but I notice my other test suits start failing with errors like these:
[image]

It seems they all need that library mocked on them as well. But why?
And what is the solution to this? I hate replication mock code on each one of them.

Comment: If other components are also refering to some external libraty, they need to have mock implementations in their respective test files. There is no solution to it, as each test suite runs independently of others.You have to replicate mock code on each on of them.

Comment: No those other files do not need that library. But somehow they are all yelling they need it. I would hate to replicate the mock code on each one of them